# Check for repeated header row in data

Tags: r, data.table, data-cleaning

Whenever I am importing data, I would like to check if there is a row thats just a repeated Header or if this happens in some of the columns. I know How do to this nicely for NA or empty values, but not just for the Name of the columne.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(mtcars)
dt2<-data.table(t(names(dt)))
names(dt2)<-names(dt)
dt<-rbind(dt,dt2)
```

I basically added the names as the last colum, I would like to check for that, for the entire row and in each column separately, to see if this is an issue when I Import unknown data.

```
colSums(dt[,lapply(.SD,is.na)])
colSums(dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) x=="")])
```

It works here for NA and empty cells to Show me how often that is an issue.
But I dont know how to check for the repeated Header.

```
colSums(dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) x==.SD)])
```

Last row does not work, because it just compares the column with itself, but it would be some how nice to just place the column names of .SD here (mpg, ...)

I would like to sea if the entire Header is repeated or if this just happens in one column.

Comment: So you are looking for any value that is the same as the column name? Can you show an example please?

Comment: Hope it is clearer now. I want to do what sotos says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the `names` of the `data.table` and count number of times the names of the column is repeated using `colSums`.

```
colSums(sapply(names(dt), function(x) dt[,x, with = FALSE] == x))

# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

In the example, as we have one row for each column having name of the column all the values are 1.

Comment: I selected this one, because it seems to be the easiest and I actually should have come up with that one myself, but I was stuck finding a simple data.table solution

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar idea as Ronak, only going rowwise instead of columnwise.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(x) dt[x,] == names(dt)))
rowSums(result)

> rowSums(result)
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11
```

So in the last row 11 elements match their column name.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option would be

```
dt[, Map(function(x, y) sum(x == y), .SD, names(.SD))]
#   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#1:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1
```

---

Or with `colSums`

```
dt[, colSums(mapply(`==`, .SD, names(.SD)))]
#   mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

---

Also, if we use `for` loop, another option is

```
v1 <- numeric(length(dt))
for(i in seq_along(dt)) v1[i] <- sum(dt[[i]] == names(dt)[i])
```

NOTE: Here we are subsetting columns with `[[` to avoid the data.table overhead